# Having trouble creating a color palette

Tags: html, css, background-color

For my project, I'm creating an app that allows users to paint pictures.

I managed to create the canvas and paint brush, and already know how to work the Javascript and Jquery.

The only problem I'm having is with creating the color palette.

**HTML**

```
<div id = "colors">
    <div style="background: #990000;"></div>
    <div style="background: #CC0000;"></div>
    <div style="background: #CC3300;"></div>
    <div style="background: #FFCC00;"></div>
    <div style="background: #FFFF00;"></div>
    <div style="background: #CCFF00;"></div>
    <div style="background: #66FF00;"></div>
    <div style="background: #003300;"></div>
    <div style="background: #33FFCC;"></div>
    <div style="background: #3300CC;"></div>
    <div style="background: #660033;"></div>
    <div style="background: #660066;"></div>
    <div style="background: #000000;"></div>
    <div style="background: #ffffff;"></div>
</div>
```

**application.css**

```
#colors {
  width: 180px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

I created a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/fqfbprd7/1/

If I add some text to the div, like I did in the fiddle, I see the colors rendered, but they are all on their separate line. Similar to paint, this should be a color selection box, where there are 7 colors per line. Just the colors though, and no text.

I even set the `width` and `height` attributes for my colors div, to render a color box.

Comment: _"7 colors per line"_ ----> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fqfbprd7/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/fqfbprd7/2/

```
#colors div {
   width: 25px;
   height: 30px;
    float: left;
 }
```

Comment: This selector selects all div elements that are `descendants` of `#colors`. The selector should probably be `#colors>div` to choose only direct children

Answer (score 1):

Target the DIV's inside **#colors** and use position **property** value of **inline-block** to get them to display next to eahch other.

```
 #colors div {
      display: inline-block;

}
```

```css
#colors {
   width: 180px;
   height: 30px;
 }

 #colors div {
      display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id ="colors">
    <div style="background: #990000">A</div>
    <div style="background: #CC0000">B</div>
 <div style="background: #CC3300">C</div>
 <div style="background: #FFCC00">D</div>
 <div style="background: #FFFF00">E</div>
 <div style="background: #CCFF00">F</div>
 <div style="background: #66FF00">G</div>
 <div style="background: #003300">H</div>
 <div style="background: #33FFCC">I</div>
 <div style="background: #3300CC">J</div>
 <div style="background: #660033">K</div>
 <div style="background: #660066">L</div>
 <div style="background: #000000">M</div>
 <div style="background: #ffffff">N</div>
</div>
```